# BIOS settings not appearing

Tags: encryption, bios, lvm

My friend installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on his Samsung NP 300 G5X laptop that had 4GB RAM and a 700GB HDD. He encrypted the Ubuntu installation and used LVM. After reboot he was taken directly to grub. He was successful in booting into Ubuntu a couple of times but then on entering passphrase he started getting this reply - 'fs type not found'. Now, he is stuck with this and cannot even boot from any live media for his BIOS settings is not appearing.

Answer (score 0):

Press the ESC button or F10 during startup to access the boot &/or BIOS menu.

https://superuser.com/questions/521389/how-do-i-boot-my-samsung-laptop-from-a-cd-dvd

http://forum.notebookreview.com/samsung/709669-getting-series-3-notebook-np300-v5a-boot-second-hdd.html